# Why the Id value is not append with Id in Jquery?

Tags: jquery

[This is my code](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Z4yYf/)

What I am expecting is
`<input type="text"  name="procedurecode1" id="procedurecode1" value="">` 
But the result like below 
`<input type="text" +idvalue="" name="procedurecode" id="procedurecode" value="">` 
I dont know why?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure of what you want but is that it : [link](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Z4yYf/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I think your quote escaping is getting confused.

It should be more like this:

You need to escape with single quotes when you're putting your variables in.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     $('#addprocedure').click(function()
{
    //alert($("#maxprocedure").val());
    var maxvalue=$("#maxprocedure").val();
    for(var i=1;i<=5;i++)
    {
        var idvalue=parseInt(maxvalue)+i;
        $("#procedurecontainer").append('<input type="text" value="" id="procedurecode'+idvalue+'" name="procedurecode'+idvalue+'" />');
        $("#maxprocedure").val(idvalue);

    }
});

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You were missing single quotes and `+`. [Here is the modified version](http://www.jsfiddle.net/Z4yYf/2/).

**Fixed Code:**

```
$("#procedurecontainer").append('<input type="text" value="" id="procedurecode"'
+ idvalue + 'name="procedurecode"' + idvalue + '></input>');
```